# Model View Controller - how to implement drawing

Tags: model-view-controller

I'm considering implementing my own (toy) MVC framework, mainly just for practise and to have fun with it. I worked with such frameworks in the past but when thinking about how I would go about it a couple of questions arose.
So what puzzles me the most is how I should tackle the drawing of the visual elements. My idea was to implement each item's drawing logic in the item's class, organize them into a tree structure, like in WPF and and pass down some sort of canvas that the elements can draw on when traverse the tree.
I'm having doubts though, whether I should pass a canvas down an entire visual tree. Another interesting thing is the handling of overlaping elements and which to draw first. I thought the visual tree would take care of that by drawing elemtns in the order they appear in a depth first search. But then I thought that the newest element should be on top no matter how close it is to the root in the tree.

So basically I couldn't really find anything on implementation best practises or details when it comes to drawing the elements and I could use some friendly advice on this or if you could point to some material that covers this it would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MVC pattern typically doesn't tackle such granular details. It ultimately comes down to decomposing the problem into three broad domains: data and logic, user input, and user output.

> I'm having doubts though, whether I should pass a canvas down an
>   entire visual tree.

How come? From a performance or coupling/responsibility perspective?

If it's performance, this is a very solid start. You do have to descend down the tree and redraw everything by default, but that can be mitigated by turning your hierarchy into an accelerator and keeping track of which portions of the screen/canvas/image need to be redrawn ("dirty regions"). Only descend down the branches that overlap this dirty region.

For the dirty regions, you can break up your canvas into a grid. As widgets need updating, mark the region(s) they occupy as needing to be redrawn. Only redraw widgets occupying those grid cells which are marked as needing to be redrawn. If you want to get really elaborate and mitigate overdraw to a minimum, you can use a quad-tree (but typically overkill for all but the most dynamic kind of systems with elaborate animating content and things like that).

It might be tempting to make this problem easier to solve to double-buffer everything and have children draw into their parents' canvases, but that's a route to gain some immediate performance in exchange for a large performance barrier at a design-level in the form of memory consumption and cache efficiency. I don't recommend this approach: double-buffer the window contents to avoid flickery artifacts, but not every single control inside of it.

If it's about coupling and responsibilities, often it's overkill from a UI context to try to decouple the rendering of a widget from the widget itself. Decoupling rendering from entities is common in game architectures through entity-component systems which would provide rendering components (typically in the form of dumb data) and defer the rendering functionality to systems, but those take a great deal of work upfront to implement for tremendous flexibility which you might never need in this kind of context.

> Another interesting thing is the handling of overlaping elements and
>   which to draw first. I thought the visual tree would take care of that
>   by drawing elemtns in the order they appear in a depth first search.
>   But then I thought that the newest element should be on top no matter
>   how close it is to the root in the tree.

The tree doesn't have to be this rigid thing. You can send siblings to the front of a child list or to the back to affect drawing order. Typically z-order changes don't occur so frequently and most of the time you'd be better off this way than transferring a great overhead to sorting the drawing on the fly as you are rendering.

Mostly I just recommend keeping it simple, especially if this is your first attempt constructing a general-purpose MVC framework. You're far more likely to err on the side of making things too complicated and painting yourself in a corner. Simple designs are pliable designs.

Comment: This was quite exhaustive. I had the impression that widget's shouldn't know about the canvas they draw to but it was only a gut feeling of sorts that there might be a cleaner solution to this. You argument is convincing though and it gave me some really good ideas. Extremely helpful, thank you.